# How to reference to an object inside of array with value and use it in v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to iterate through an array of objects that build an input field, the systemName value of the object is the name of the second array key value.
I'm trying to point to it in the v-model and i get an error.
It looks something like this:

```js
    <script>
        let item = {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "joe",
            "metas": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "key": "type",
                    "value": "Phone Call"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "key": "source",
                    "value": "facebook"
                }
            ]
        };
    
        let customFields = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "type": "text",
                "systemName": "type"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "type": "text",
                "systemName": "source"
            }
        ]
    </script>
    <div v-for="field in customFields">
        <input v-model="item.metas.find(i => i.key === field.systemName).value" :label="field.systemName" :placeholder="field.systemName" type="text">
    </div>
```

Is there any way to search and point to the right object in the model?

Comment: No error is reproducible from this code

Answer (score 0):

You should add `computed` prop and gather `item.metas` and `customFields` there:

```js
computed: {
  customFieldsAndMetas () {
     return this.customFields.map(x => ({
       field: x,
       meta: this.item.metas.find(i => i.key === field.systemName)
     }))
  }
}
```

and use it in a template like this:

```html
<div v-for="fieldAndMeta in customFieldsAndMetas">
  <input v-model="fieldAndMeta.meta.value" :label="fieldAndMeta.field.systemName" :placeholder="fieldAndMeta.field.systemName" type="text">
</div>
```